# Stack execution (python methods) without decorators

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I kindly ask for help in solving the following problem: accessing the stack of methods, with the "function name", "arguments" of the function (values) and the return, which has just been executed.

In short: get the chain of execution of methods, with name, arguments and return.

Is there any way to do this **without putting decorators** in each method?

I have already tried with the traceback module, but it does not work since it shows only the "back" string of the main method below.

I tried with the StackSummary / FrameSummary, but without success too = (

```
def func_a(param_a1):
    print('Executing function A with: {0}'.format(param_a1))
    func_b("a", "b")

    return "ok"

def func_b(param_b1, param_b2):
    print('Executing function B with: {0}, {1}'.format(param_b1, param_b2))
    return None

def func_c():
    print('Executing function C without args')
    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Call function_a()
    func_a("testing params")

    # Get here???
    # call func_a("testing params")
    #    -> call func_b("a", "b")
    #         -> call func_c()
    #            returning None
    #       returning None
    # returning "ok"
```

Thank you for your attention

Comment: Maybe the [`profile`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/profile.html) module can help you.

Comment: `return None` is redundant. A function with no return value returns none.

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @DavidCullen maybe if there were other return paths in the function